# Reading from a file using scanner, line by line and creating an object out of the data

Tags: java, file-io

I am tasked with reading a file line by line using scanner and creating Student objects from each line.

This is the layout of the text file:

```
id,first_name,last_name,username,password,UserType,permission,course,degree
35,Bartholom,Sapsedidiy,wbeeseb3,Q8yPvK4qm,Student,Reserve,EngineerI,Legal
```

I have made sure that each attribute is going into thenewly created student object are in the correct order.

I am trying to get each next string or int after each comma and assign it to the relevant attribute that it is:

```
try
    {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Student.txt"));
        input.useDelimiter(",");

        while(input.hasNext()) {
            int id = input.nextInt();
            String firstName = input.next();
            String lastName = input.next();
            String userName = input.next();
            String passWord = input.next();
            String type = input.next();
            enumUserType userType = enumUserType.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
            String permission = input.next();
            enumPermissionType permissionType = enumPermissionType.valueOf(permission.toUpperCase());
            String course = input.next();
            String degree = input.next();

            Address userAddress = new Address(1, 23, "Fake street", "Suburb1", 2500, enumState.NSW);
            User user = new Student(id, firstName, lastName, userName, passWord, userType, permissionType, true, course, degree, userAddress);
            getLibrary().addUser(user);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
```

The thing is straight away i get an input mismatch exception on the int id which is the first read value, i am not sure what is going wrong here and i need some help to fix this error,

i am only fairly new to learning read/write on file.
Maybe i have something in the wrong order or its reading the wrong values some how?

Thank you in advance!

edit:
my error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at library.Library.initData(Library.java:262)
at library.Library.main(Library.java:225)
```

Line 262 is: int id = input.nextInt();

Comment: Can you share the log or the error message? That will give others more insight into what is happening.

Comment: Just edited the main post, hope it gives some insight.

Comment: id,first_name,last_name,username,password,UserType,permission,course,degree

Comment: You should skip the first line and then take the inputs. Your first line contains only string whereas you want to store it in integers and string.

Comment: That's a very good point! unfortunately i just removed the first line and put the second line with the data as the first and saved and still getting the exact same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
try
    {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Student.txt"));
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] line = input.nextLine().split(",");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
            String firstName = line[1];
            String lastName = line[2];
            String userName = line[3];
            String passWord = line[4];
            String type = line[5];
            enumUserType userType = enumUserType.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
            String permission = line[6];
            enumPermissionType permissionType = enumPermissionType.valueOf(permission.toUpperCase());
            String course = line[7];
            String degree = line[8];

            Address userAddress = new Address(1, 23, "Fake street", "Suburb1", 2500, enumState.NSW);
            User user = new Student(id, firstName, lastName, userName, passWord, userType, permissionType, true, course, degree, userAddress);
            getLibrary().addUser(user);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
```

Alternatively, this can also be achieved using Scanner.

```
try
    {
        input = new Scanner(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\Student.txt"));
        while(input.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner line = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
            line.useDelimiter(",");
            int id = line.nextInt();
            String firstName = line.next();
            String lastName = line.next();
            String userName = line.next();
            String passWord = line.next();
            String type = line.next();
            enumUserType userType = enumUserType.valueOf(type.toUpperCase());
            String permission = line.next();
            enumPermissionType permissionType = enumPermissionType.valueOf(permission.toUpperCase());
            String course = line.next();
            String degree = line.next();

            Address userAddress = new Address(1, 23, "Fake street", "Suburb1", 2500, enumState.NSW);
            User user = new Student(id, firstName, lastName, userName, passWord, userType, permissionType, true, course, degree, userAddress);
            getLibrary().addUser(user);

        }
    }
    catch(IOException io)
    {
        System.out.println("Error opening file");
    }
```

But the previous one has been my preferred way.